# Animate ListView Item To Top of List

Tags: android

I am making an activity where you can share content with contacts. I show a list of contacts which is backed by a cursor.

The requirement is to animate an item(contact) to the top of the list when it is clicked. It looks like so

[image]

The problems I am facing are 
1. how to animate and item through the listview.
2. how to remove and item from the cursor. I get the contacts like so

```
contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
```

Does this make sense to have the list work in this way?

Comment: How should the animation behave?

Comment: Well I am open to suggestions. But moving up the list would be nice. I am open to suggestions really. Going up 1 item at a time would be nice but I don't know how the other items should react to that.

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll to the selected item you can use the following listener

```
   private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener clickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            int initial_position = adapterView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            int delta = i - initial_position;

            ((ListView)adapterView).smoothScrollByOffset(delta);
        }
    };
```

(please note that need level API 11).

Instead, for remove an item from a cursor you should remove the contact related but I don't think is what you want.